# Cards Spacing in CSS

Tags: css

Update:  Thank you everyone for the suggestions.  I didn't realize it was this simple.

I am currently working on a 'cards' in CSS and I can't seem to get rid of a small white space between card row 1 and card row 2.  Any suggestions on how to remove it.  The animation would look much smoother without it.

```css
/* cards */
.dank.cards { margin:0; padding:0; list-style-type:none; }
.dank.cards li { width:50%; float:left; overflow:hidden; position:relative; }
.dank.cards li:hover img { transform:scale(1.1); }
.dank.cards li img { max-width:100%; -webkit-transition: transform 1s; transition: transform 1s; }
.dank.cards .dank.content { position:absolute; top:0; left:0; }
```

```html
<ul class="dank cards slideRight">
   <li><img src="http://neil.computer/s/1.jpg" /><div class="dank content">Cool</div></li>
   <li><img src="http://neil.computer/s/1.jpg" /><div class="dank content">Amazing</div></li>
   <li><img src="http://neil.computer/s/1.jpg" /><div class="dank content">Sweet</div></li>
   <li><img src="http://neil.computer/s/1.jpg" /><div class="dank content">Wow</div></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Images are by default inline elements.
So setting style `display:block;` to the image element will resolve your issue.

Just set

```
<img src="http://neil.computer/s/1.jpg" style="display:block;"/>
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

Use `display:block;` in your img style.

```
.dank.cards li img {
    display:block
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's very easy to get rid of this issue, just add `display:block;` to the images

```
.dank.cards li img{
    display:block;
}
```